# get selected value from js in Jinja

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I would like to get the selected item from the form in my Jinja Code. Is this possible?

This is my Html/Jinja Code, where I iterate over my users from the database.

```
<form>
    <label>Select a User</label>
        <select id="mySelect">
        {%for user in List%}
            <option value="{{ user.uuid }}">{{ user.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
    <button onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Show Users History</button>
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

This is my js code, which describes very well what I want, I guess:
if a user is selected by the button, I want p to display the users name.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var result = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        var HTML = '{%for user in List%}{% if user.uuid == ' + result + '%} user.name {%endif%}{%endfor%}';
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = HTML;
    }
</script>
```

this isn't working and I can't find another way to do this.

Comment: If you want to just show the name then you can simply display the innertext like `document.getElementById("mySelect").innerText, which gives you name of selected person, an please tell how it is not working, any error? What is the result and what you were expecting

Comment: @charchit i want to display something more complicated, so I need to check if results == user.uuid

Comment: What is the problem,  according to me it should print what you are trying, are there any errors. Or there is no result, in what sense it is not working, please can you explain.

Comment: @charchit the code is not working. is doesn't print the users name, because the if statement is not true.

Comment: Are you sure that , myfunction is executed try logging something, also you should pass parameter e to function and then use `e.preventDefault()` rather then returning false. Which you are doing in html onclick.

Comment: @charchit I'm sorry, i don't really get what you mean. Could you please tell me what code lines I should change in what?

Comment: Remove `return false` from onclick function in html and add `e.preventDefault()` myFunction

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        const select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>
```

So the idea is get a reference to the `select` element of which we can retrieve the `options` and grab a specific option by using the `select` elements' `selectedIndex` attribute.